# How do I retrieve multiple callbacks on translation progress

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge

I have created a webhook that is using the even extraction.updated that should trigger when a job is in progress. I want to retrieve multiple calls on the progress of the translation so that I can show it in my progress bar. Unfortunately I only retrieve a callback when the job translation is finished. When I create the job I set the misc.workflow parameter and same goes for the hook. Am I missing some parameters when creating a webhook or posting a job?

I was following this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/

The job payload takes the input which is my urn, output which is the filetype(svf2) and views(2d,3d), and misc which is the workflow(testworkflowname)

Callback result:

```
{{
  "version": "1.0",
  "resourceUrn": "<my-resourceUrn>",
  "hook": {
    "hookId": "<my-hookId>",
    "tenant": "testworkflowname",
    "callbackUrl": "<my-callbackUrl>",
    "createdBy": "<my-createdBy>",
    "event": "extraction.updated",
    "createdDate": "<my-createdDate>",
    "lastUpdatedDate": "<my-lastUpdatedDate>",
    "system": "derivative",
    "creatorType": "Application",
    "status": "active",
    "scope": {
      "workflow": "testworkflowname"
    },
    "hookAttribute": {
      "progress": "test"
    },
    "autoReactivateHook": false,
    "urn": "<my-urn>"
  },
  "payload": {
    "TimeStamp": <my-timestamp>,
    "Env": "production",
    "URN": "<my-urn>",
    "EventType": "UPDATED",
    "Payload": {
      "status": "success",
      "bubble": {
        "guid":"<my-guid>",
        "owner": "<my-owner>",
        "hasThumbnail": "true",
        "startedAt": "my-startedAt>",
        "type": "design",
        "urn":"<my-urn>",
        "success": "100%",
        "progress": "complete",
        "region": "US",
        "status": "success",
        "children": []
      },
      "scope": "<my-scope>",
      "registerKey": []
    },
    "WorkflowAttributes": null
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your webhooks setup correctly. I'm afraid this is a limitation on the Model Derivative service side. The service can translate over 60 different file formats today, and as you can imagine, different formats must be converted using different libraries. And while some of the converters support progress reporting, others may not, so being able to get notified of translation progress really depends on the file format you're processing.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I am only translating nwd files at this point. Do you know if the Model Derivatie service supports progress reporting for this kind of file?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. Let me ask the Model Derivative service engineering team, and get back to you.

Comment: According to the engineering team, NWD files **do** report intermediate progress (not just `0%` and then `100%`). Is it possible that the specific NWD file in your case was simple, and therefore translated too fast?

Comment: It might be the case, the file I was testing with was around 25mb.